# Z-index problem on IE7

Tags: css, debugging, internet-explorer-7, z-index

**this question is on bounty because the below answers did not solve the problem.

I am debugging a page in IE7 and have run into one problem. When you hover over a nav link, the dropdown falls below the slide below it. The dropdown ul is positioned absolutely with a z-index of 10 and the slider is positioned relative to its parent with a z-index of 1. Something within the #slider is causing the menu to fall behind it.

You can view it at [vitaminjdesign.com/search](http://www.vitaminjdesign.com/search)

I used jquery to change the z-indexes of every child of #slider:

```
$(function() {
      $('.jFlowSlideContainer').css('z-index', '1');
        })
      $(function() {
          $('#jFlowSlide').css('z-index', '1');
        })
      $(function() {
          $('#slides').css('z-index', '1');
        })
```

Still, in IE7, the submenu sits behind the slider. Perhaps the problem is lying in the menu script?

Comment: Link gives `Internal Server Error`. You've more to do ;) Even then, preferably post an SSCCE so that we can just copy'n'paste'n'run it to see the exact problem. Thus, from `<html>` until with `</html>` with the **minimum** required code to reproduce the problem (don't forget the doctype...). http://sscce.org

Comment: In my IE7, the drop down menu doesn't even epand. It keeps its `display: none` even on hovering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context). Basically the `#menu li` elements on which you have set a z-index (to 9) are not in the same stacking context as the `#slider` element (on which you have set z-index to 1). A quick solution would be to set the z-index of your `#header` element to 2, however I'd recommend reading up on stacking contexts.

Comment: Yup,
A quick hack  would be to set the z-index in de header id:

<div id="header" style="z-index:500">

It's on the same level as slider in the same parent(contentwrap), thus setting a z-index will work. 
Setting a z-index on the menuitems wil not work because of the rules of stacking.

Therefore +1 for the link on stacking contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the ul Or the li height:auto. It's hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: that doesnt do it, take a look now, the link above is working

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several problems. I took out everything between `<div id='slider'> ... </div>` and filled it with dummy text, so i could see if the menu was going over or under. It was still going under. I had a look at the rules in style.css for #slider, and removed the position: rule, to get the following:

```
#slider {
Z-INDEX: 1 !important; FLOAT: left; WIDTH: 960px; HEIGHT: 296px;
}
```

And that seemed to make it work. Then I added the slider content back in, and it was broken again. =\

Comment: I did the same thing and gave it a background color. Without removing the position:relative it was working perfectly. Then I put the slider element back in and it was broken. SO, the problem is created by the slider. Im gonna get my hands dirty with the slider js

Answer (score -1):

```
position:relative;
float:left;
height:296px;
z-index:1!important;
```

to z-index exists the position needs to be "absolute" and the display "block"

```
position:absolute;
display:block;
z-index:1!important;
```

greetings